# Dictionary Comprehension Syntax Understanding

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I was working with someone on here who helped me solve a problem by using list comprehnsion to populate a dictionary. I have an output called bar that contains open high low and close data and I just wanted to assign them to a dictionary. 
Example of the data:

```
Timestamp: 2019-07-17 10:58:00+00:00
Open: 1.8877
High: 1.8878
Low: 1.8871
Close: 1.8878
```

We did that via this code:

```
def append(self, bar):
    symbols = symbol = ['CLE', 'RBE']
    bar_keys = key = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']
    self.newest_bar = {key: getattr(bar, key) for key in bar_keys}
```

So it'll essentially get the bar.Open, bar.Close etc for every value in the list bar_keys.

I'm essentially trying to add on top of this a 2nd symbol and trying to use the same exact syntax but I'm not sure why it's not working.

I just want to now just take the bar.Close value for each symbol (CLE, RBE) and add them to my dictionary but I keep getting unhashable type. What is the difference between the working version above and my version below?

```
symbols = symbol = ['CLE', 'RBE']
self.closes = {key: getattr(bar, 'Close') for symbol in symbols}
```

this is the whole code snippet with his working version and what ive added:

```
def append(self, bar):
    symbols = symbol = ['CLE', 'RBE']
    bar_keys = key = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']
    self.newest_bar = {key: getattr(bar, key) for key in bar_keys}
    self.bars[bar.Timestamp] = self.newest_bar
    self.closes = {key: getattr(bar, 'Close') for symbol in symbols}
```

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: that is not a list comprehension, that is a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: why are you even doing `symbols = symbol = ` and `bar_keys = key = `? And also, in the first code you're not even using the `symbols`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key` is a list. You can't key a dict with a list. In the other code, the `key` from inside the dict comprehension is used instead.

Stop using the same variable name for a bunch of different things.

```
def append(self, bar):
    symbols = ['CLE', 'RBE']
    bar_keys = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']
    self.newest_bar = {key: getattr(bar, key) for key in bar_keys}
    self.bars[bar.Timestamp] = self.newest_bar
    self.closes = {symbol: getattr(bar, 'Close') for symbol in symbols}
```

Comment: ohh - i thought "key" in the working example was needed to define the keys of the dictionary.

Comment: In the working example, `key` is set with an individual object from `bar_keys` by the dict comprehension. If you wanted to use those key values again in your new code you'd have to iterate through `bar_keys` with a loop or comprehension.